# Disallow automatic download of pdf files

Tags: html, apache, pdf

Is it possible to disable that pdf files aren't downloaded automatically to the temporary (or download) folders of a browser. I want to do this on the server side.

My problem is that there are a couple sensitive pdf files on the webserver. Many of the users aren't aware that, when viewing pdf files, they are saved locally to the computer.

Is there a (or different) solution?

Like embedding the pdf in HTML with some specific tags?
Or creating the pdf with some specific (security) parameters?

Thanks regards Patrik

Comment: Want to disable client side caching as well?

Comment: A service like Scribd may be exactly what you are looking for, it is PDF viewing via Flash. Otherwise I don't imagine it is possible to have someone view the file without saving a copy locally.

Comment: No. If are worried about sensitive information, don't put it on the web.

Comment: The user can download the pdf if he/she wants to. I'm more worried about those users who maybe using a public computer and not knowing that the file is downloaded automatically to the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A server can only suggest to the browser not to cache the files it is sending. A client may or many not follow those suggestions.

Recently, I wrote an article illustrating how to create a [PDF web viewer using a Java applet](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=195&t=A_Java_PDF_Web_Viewer_-_Powered_By_PDFOne_%28for_Java_trade;%29). (NOTE: This applet uses PDF components from our product PDFOne (for Java).)

For your needs, you will have to modify the applet so that it downloads an encrypted PDF from the server, decrypts it on the client, displays it and when the user is finished with it deletes it.

Comment: How can the server suggest to the client not to download the file when viewing?

Comment: You are thinking that PDF plugins can do what flash does for streaming videos. Play them but not save them. For this, the PDF plugin needs to be designed that way. Most PDF browser plugins expect the PDF file to be downloaded and saved. Even with streaming videos, the file is downloaded temporarily. The plugin destroys it after playing it. If you want that kind of functionality, you need to talk to Adobe. They will not listen to you because that is not what the users want.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, you can create a custom Java applet that displays the PDF and destroys it afterwards. For that, you need a Java PDF viewer component.

Answer (score 0):

If your PDF has an independent URL, you have no way to prevent downloading it. @KyleWpppd in his comment suggested a variant of using Flash plug-in for displaying PDF. This would work and would prevent saving by an average Joe, but not by a hacker of a good IT specialist. So the only more or less working (but not 100%) way would be to have some flash or other module which would communicate with the server and dynamically request the document on page by page basis. This is a complicated task and, as said, doesn't give a guarantee, but at least moves the stealing task much higher in complexity rating. So indeed, if you need 100% protection, - don't put the document to computer at all (as it can be copied).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this isn't a security issue. If some user wants to download the file it's ok for me. I just don't want it to download the pdf file by default (when the user views it)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Eugene that the problem lies in the fact that the PDF is downloadable. If you want the user to be able to view the document but not be able to save it, then you may consider a solution such as this one:
http://www.tallcomponents.com/livedemos/pdfwebviewer1-library/

Disclosure: I am affiliated with the company that sells this product.